# Is there a better way than this to write Python functions that "depend on parameters"?

Tags: python, function, lambda, closures

Consider the Python function `line` defined as follows:

```py
def line(m, b):
    def inner_function(x):
        return m * x + b
    return inner_function
```

This function has the property that for any floats `m` and `b`, the object `line(m, b)` is a Python function, and when `line(m, b)` is called on a float `x`, it returns a float `line(m, b)(x)`.  The float `line(m, b)(x)` can be interpreted as the value of the line with slope `m` and y-intercept `b` at the point `x`.  This is one method for writing a Python function that "depends on parameters" `m` and `b`.

1. Is there a special name for this method of writing a Python function that depends on some parameters?
2. Is there a more Pythonic and/or computationally efficient way to write a function that does the same thing as `line` above?

Comment: What about this is not "Pythonic"?  What about it is not efficient?

Comment: These are called [`closures`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) - they are common, useful, and perfectly acceptable to write.

Comment: You can write a one-liner: `line = lambda m, b: lambda x: m * x + b`, but your code is absolutely fine ("pythonic") anyway

Comment: @ScottHunter I didn't mean to imply that there's anything that's *not* "Pythonic" or efficient about it -- was just curious if there's a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a closure, and it's a perfectly reasonable way to write one, as well as one of the most efficient means of doing so (in the CPython reference interpreter anyway).

The only other common pattern I know of is the equivalent of C++'s functors, where a class has the state as attributes, and the additional parameters are passed to `__call__`, e.g. to match your case:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, m, b):
        self.m = m
        self.b = b
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.m * x + self.b
```

It's used identically, either creating/storing an instance and reusing it, or as in your example, creating it, using it once, and throwing it away (`Line(m, b)(x)`). Functors are slower than closures though (as attribute access is more expensive than reading from nested scope, at least in the CPython reference interpreter), and as you can see, they're more verbose as well, so I'd generally recommend the closure unless your needs require the greater flexibility/power of class instances.

Comment: `partial` of some `line(m, b, x)` is also another option

Comment: Also related to @ShadowRanger's answer, OP may find [object closure duality](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9363635) interesting

Comment: @modesitt: Similar I suppose, though it's used differently; a `line` function taking all three parameters would have to exist, and the wrapping would be done either directly with `partial` or with yet another utility function.

Answer (score 3):

I support @ShaddowRanger's answer.  But using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is another nice approach.

```
import functools
def f(m, b, x):
    return m * x + b
line = functools.partial(f, 2, 3)
line(5)
=> 13
```

One thing which is worth pointing out is that `lambda` objects, and OP's `inner_function` aren't pickleable, whereas `line` here, as well as @ShaddowRanger's `Line` objects are, which makes them a bit more useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little shorter:

```
def line(m,b):
    return lambda x: m*x+b;
```

Comment: if we are gonna go this route, `lambda m, b: lambda x: m*x+b` ;)

Comment: Note that in real code, you'd ideally be annotating both inner and outer functions with docstrings; `lambda`s make for nice one-liners, but not so much for documentation.

Comment: @modesitt:The difference is that the *only* use of `inner_function` was inside of `line`, which might not be the case for `line`.